# Assign window.matchMedia.addEventListener to a variable makes it fail to run

Tags: javascript, color-scheme

I want to detect dark mode change in JavaScript. Things work fine when I call `window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").addEventListener` directly.

However, when I assign `window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").addEventListener` to a variable:

```js
var func = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").addEventListener;
func("change", () => console.log("test"));
```

The EventListener function does not run.

Code to reproduce:

```js
function test_1() {
  var MediaQueryList = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

  MediaQueryList.addEventListener("change", () => {
    console.log("Call MediaQueryList.addEventListener");
  });
}

function test_2() {
  var MediaQueryList = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
  var func = MediaQueryList.addEventListener;

  func("change", () => {
    console.log("Call MediaQueryList.addEventListener use variable");
  });
}

test_1();
test_2();
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/sortujayde/pen/jOYLEaK?editors=1111

Chrome version: 99.0.4844.84

Comment: The function `test_1()` was called but function `test_2()` wasn't call `console.log` in all browsers. Maybe because incorrect syntax `func('change')`? However in Google Chrome did work on  `test_1()`. The `console.log` did write the message but you need to change dark mode from Windows, not Chrome itself. [Read the document](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9275525?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).

Comment: @vee In Chrome, there is a "Rendering" tab which could emulate `prefers-color-scheme`. I don't think this is a syntax problem as `MediaQueryList.addEventListener` and `func` should be identical function and their arguments should be the same.